# Scrape data from ajax loaded table into excel using VBA

Tags: ajax, excel, vba, web-scraping

I've got a problem with one case that I want to resolve. 
I've a web-page with 3 tables that are loaded by clicking the button (ajax response). User is selecting the date ranges and after button is clicked data is populated to tables.
What I want to do is to take those tables into excel using VBA, so within one click I can copy those tables from page to excel.

I've searched the internet, but didn't found something that regards to similar issue.

Currently I've macro to download those tables, but by default they are empty, so the code downloads only headers.

```
      Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

Dim H As Object, B$, D As Object, C As Object


Set C = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
Set D = CreateObject("HTMLFile")
Set H = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

 H.SetAutoLogonPolicy 0

 H.Open "GET", "https://mywebpage.com"
 H.Send

 D.body.innerHTML = H.ResponseText

 C.SetText D.getElementById("table").outerHTML
 C.PutInClipboard

Worksheets("sheet1").[A1].PasteSpecial
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells.Hyperlinks.Delete

End Sub
```

Does anyone have some idea how to call ajax function (with time parameters that are chosen in the page) from the excel visual basic?

Comment: Actually using single letter variable names is one of the worst idea you can have. This makes your code incredibly hard to read understand and maintain. If you want to do yourself, us, everyone you are working with, a favor change them to something meaningful. You will end up with much better maintainability and possibly less errors.

Comment: I will remember, but that does not nothing to the problem I've described.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the page or show its html/js?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. The page is in our company local network and there is no access to it outside of the network. I do not have also the source code for it as I was not developing it, I just want to scrape the data.

Comment: Get the data where webserver gets it (datbase?)! Get the script that creates the page and see where data comes from.

Comment: The best way would be: Ask the guys in your company that provide the intranet, so they either provide you the data source directly or provide you a REST API so you can access the data via intranet (without scraping the web page, which might change and break your code). • Actually it is impossible to help you without seeing the HTML code of the webpage. • Also Ajax makes it much more difficult to scrape a page correctly (which is why APIs are so great and easy to use).

Comment: *"does not nothing to the problem I've described"* you are right, but it does (indirectly), because if people here have a hard time to read/understand your code it is less likely to get a good answer ;) You increase the probability to help you by making it easy to understand your issue and support people trying to help you.

Comment: We need to see the ajax calls. There is no way IMO that the question can currently be answered and thus is off-topic. We should be able to reproduce your problem ideally. Perhaps find a similar example with a public endpoint.  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [MCVE]

Comment: @shadow First look over AJAX requests in a browser dev tools network tab, there are [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+vba+web-scraping+network+tab). BTW all source codes could be viewed from dev tools network and sources tabs.